# Android OnClick error

Tags: android

I am currently working through a Java Android book and have hit a problem. I am creating a basic sudoku app and am trying to add a OnClickListener so that when someone hits the 'About' button it displays text, whenever this button is hit I just get the error message as follows. 'The application Sudoku has stopped, please try again.

Here is my code

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.example.sudoku"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".Sudoku"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity 
            android:name=".About"
            android:label="@string/about_title">
         </activity>   

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
      </activity>

     </application>

</manifest>
```

I have an about class

```
package org.example.sudoku;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class About extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);
    }

}
```

and lastly is my Sudoku java class

```
package org.example.sudoku;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Sudoku extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //set up listeners for buttons
        View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
        continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View newButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
        newButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
        aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);



    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.about_button:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks for looking at this and I'm using eclipse by the way, tryed using the Logcat and De-Bugger but no luck.

**LogCat errors**

```
02-13 20:33:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 20:33:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(524): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {org.example.sudoku/org.example.sudoku.About}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-13 20:33:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1508)
02-13 20:33:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
02-13 20:33:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
02-13 20:33:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
02-13 20:33:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at org.example.sudoku.Sudoku.onClick(Sudoku.java:34)
02-13 20:33:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
02-13 20:33:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
02-13 20:33:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-13 20:33:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-13 20:33:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-13 20:33:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-13 20:33:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 20:33:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-13 20:33:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-13 20:33:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-13 20:33:08.376: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the lines from the`Logcat` with the `Exception`(red). Go to the `Logcat` and in your left click on `All messages(no filter)` if you don't see anything in the `Logcat`.

Comment: In your manifest you have probably a problem with an inner activity. Your tag <activity>About </activity> is inside <activity> Sudoku.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the reason, but ur manifest file seems messed up. Those two activity tags are mingled together. You should change the application part to:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".Sudoku"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>   
    <activity 
        android:name=".About"
        android:label="@string/about_title">
    </activity>

 </application>
```

Comment: Ill try the above, added the errors from the logCat I was just following the book with the layout in the manifest file. Thanks

Comment: From the error msgs, it seems the system can't find the activity declaration. The manifest change should help.

Answer (score 1):

you have defined activity wrong in manifest. A part of it should be as below:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".Sudoku"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <activity 
            android:name=".About"
            android:label="@string/about_title">
         </activity>  

     </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button aboutButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.about_button);
if (aboutButton != null)
    aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
else
    Log.e("MyTag", "aboutButton not found on View");
```

Also make sure to edit your manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.example.sudoku"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".Sudoku"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
      </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".About"
            android:label="@string/about_title">
         </activity>  

     </application>

</manifest>
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks for this, whilst i appreciate your answer, could you possibly explain to me what was wrong with my orginal solution as this is the one it gives you in the book and as I'm working through the book I don't want to go off track if you know what i mean

Comment: Your Manifest.xml is corrupted. You defined your "About" Activity in the SudokuActivity. It's also good to cast your result from the findViewById(resource) to the class you expect it to be. If you dont cast your result you are working with a View object which dont know methods from Buttons, Textviews and so on.

Comment: ah right, that makes sense damn book, obviously this needs its own activity. where do i thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
            android:name=".Sudoku"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity 
            android:name=".About"
            android:label="@string/about_title">
         </activity>   

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

should be :

```
<activity>
       android:name=".Sudoku"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
 </activity>

 <activity 
       android:name=".About"
       android:label="@string/about_title">
  </activity>
```