# crash on Splash to Menu

Tags: android, andengine

when the splash screen moveed to the menu, the program crashed.
The logcat details while crash are as follows :

```
04-24 11:40:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1508)
04-24 11:40:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
04-24 11:40:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
04-24 11:40:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
04-24 11:40:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at com.pearson.lagp.v3.StartActivity$1.run(StartActivity.java:68)
04-24 11:40:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-24 11:40:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-24 11:40:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 11:40:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
04-24 11:40:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 11:40:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 11:40:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
04-24 11:40:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
04-24 11:40:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(3180):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this is my program about screen moving:

```
package com.pearson.lagp.v3;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions.ScreenOrientation;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.font.Font;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;
import org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
public class StartActivity extends BaseGameActivity {
    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 320;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;
    private TextureRegion mSplashTextureRegion;
    private Font mFont;
    private Handler mHandler;

    public Engine onLoadEngine() {
        mHandler=new Handler();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mLaunchTask);
        this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        return new Engine(
            new EngineOptions(
                true,
                ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE,
                new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT),
                this.mCamera
            )
        );
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadResources() {
        mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(512, 512,TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        mSplashTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(
            this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "Splashscreen.png", 0, 0
        );
        this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas);
    }
    @Override
    public Scene onLoadScene() {
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
        final Scene scene = new Scene(1);
        /* Center the splash on the camera. */
        final int centerX =(CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mSplashTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
        final int centerY =(CAMERA_HEIGHT -this.mSplashTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;
        /* Create the sprite and add it to the scene. */
        final Sprite splash = new Sprite(centerX,centerY, this.mSplashTextureRegion);
        scene.getLastChild().attachChild(splash);
        return scene;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask, 3000);
    }

    private Runnable mLaunchTask=new Runnable(){
        public void run(){

            Intent mIntent=new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
            StartActivity.this.startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    };
}
```

And this is my Manifest after modify:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pearson.lagp.v3"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.pearson.lagp.v3.StartActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.pearson.lagp.v3.MainMenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/menu_name">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

why it crashed?

Comment: there are some other part remained you didn't post of your `LogCat`. Please, post that portion aslo.

Comment: also call  `mHandler.removeCallbacks()` to remove handler after first call

Comment: I added mHandler.removeCallbacks() after mHandler=new Handler();, but error still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declare your activity in manifest?

or

Check your activity on manifest with right package name?

[Android OnClick error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267804/android-onclick-error)

[Unable to find explicit activity class and unable to instantiate activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737075/unable-to-find-explicit-activity-class-and-unable-to-instantiate-activity)

Comment: I modified my manifest, but here still are other errors:
04-24 11:40:17.082: E/AndroidRuntime(3180):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

Comment: it means problem in your handler and plz show your whole code

Answer (score 0):

try this .. your activity should be decalred like this in manifest

```
    android:name="com.example.namespace.Firstactivity"
```

(or) intent filter in your manifest is declared in wrong place. rename your activitynames and post your manifest.